Android Gradle : Execute wrapper task first and then compile the project
I am executing my project in command-line like given below

.\gradlew wrapper clean build

For some reasons, I want my project to be built with downgraded gradle version 6.1.1 as mentioned in below task. But the build is getting failed since the distribution URL in gradle-wrapper.properties has "7.5" version. I don't want to change anything manually here.
tasks.named("wrapper", Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion "6.1.1"
    distributionType Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}

Please do provide some idea on how to execute the wrapper the very first time before the project
starts compiling.
